# Compile-time check for existence of an enum member

Tags: c, gcc, clang

This question is rather theoretical, I don't have a real life example at hand, it's just somethig I had encountered a couple of times and wondered if there's a generic way to solve.

Let's say I have a program interfacing with a library that exposes an enum. Depending on the library version, some enum members may exist, and some may not.
I want to compile conditional code based on their existence. I know there are other best-practices, like `#if`-ing on the library version. In some cases, however, it's cleanest and easiest to just check the existence of enums.

Some code I've seen follow this convention when declaring enums:

```
enum foo {
    foo_bar = 1
#define foo_bar foo_bar
    foo_baz = 2
#define foo_baz foo_baz
    ...
};
```

this lets me use `#ifdef foo_XXX` to check the existence of a member of `enum foo`. But it's not always available, of course.

Is there any way to test for the definition of a "name" in the current lexical scope? I'm specifically targeting enums but a more general answer is accepted as well :) I assume there's no "standard C" way to do so, thus GCC-only or clang-only solutions apply as well.

**EDIT:** After contemplating a bit on it, I implemented a small GCC "builtin" that I called `__builtin_compile_time_ifdef`. It accepts a name as a*string* and returns 1 if the name is defined. It works fine. The problem that remains is that in all constructs I know of that provide conditional evaluation (`__builtin_choose_expr`, `_Generic`), the non-evaluated branch is still checked for undeclared names. So if I want to use the name (and not just check for existence), I can't.

Comment: When you refer to `foo_bar` in the code, the compiler will flag an error if it does not exist. Isn't the point of using `enum` that you refer to it by name, not by value?

Comment: My code tries to target multiple versions of e.g library "foo". In some version, "foo" add the enum member `bazbaz`. When available, I wish to use it. When not available, I want my code to do something else instead.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Why not just use the latest version of the library instead of trail-and-error, which may be disastrous? You might invent a name that does not exist, but actually does under another name.

Comment: This seems better suited for a configure script.

Comment: @WeatherVane I intentionally said this question is theoretical. I don't have a real case from lately where I needed this. I'm not looking for other best practices, like pinning the library version - I'm curious specifically about this question.

Comment: @Shawn yes, one of the common practices is to use a configure script which will try to build a program using the possibly-defined name and see if GCC's invocation passes without errors. I **am** wondering if there's an easier / cleaner solution to do this test, without needing an external script :)

Comment: I've never seen any code that has a test like you're looking for. The reason is simple. Conditional compilation is performed by the preprocessor, and the preprocessor only has a list of preprocessor symbols created with `#define`. It has no concept of *"a "name" in the current lexical scope"*. In fact, it has no concept of lexical scope. That comes much later in the compilation process, long after the preprocessor has finished.

Comment: As long as you're writing builtins, can you make one that evaluates the name if it exists, and otherwise yields -1 or some other sentinel value?

Comment: @NateEldredge Guess that's what I'll do haha. Will update here if I get something I find convenient enough.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of such a feature, and the [GNU cpp manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) doesn't describe anything of the sort.  Indeed, in [the description of `#if`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If), they explicitly say that `enum` constants are not recognized.

Moreover, such a feature would be contrary to the overall design scheme of the preprocessor.  `cpp` is not supposed to attempt to parse its input as C; it only looks for preprocessor directives and macros to expand.  Indeed, people often use `cpp` to preprocess code in other languages (e.g. assembly).  If the preprocessor tried to recognize the `enum` keyword and parse its syntax, it would be likely to be horribly confused by other languages that might use the string `enum` in completely different ways, contrary to people's expectations.  So I wouldn't think there's any chance that someone would have created what you're looking for.

This is a problem that people are expected to solve in other ways (which you mentioned in comments that you already know about).

Comment: I might not have been clear enough - I'm not asking specifically about the preprocessor (I gave its example because I want something similar to its behavior). I'm sure that if there's a way to do it, that way won't be through the preprocessor :(

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I wrote [a PoC plugin](https://github.com/Jongy/gcc_builtin_lookup_name) demonstrating what I needed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

enum x {
    v1 = 1,
    // v2 = 2
};

void main(void) {
    enum x v1 = (enum x)__builtin_lookup_name("v1", (enum x)-1);
    enum x v2 = (enum x)__builtin_lookup_name("v2", (enum x)-1);

    printf("%d %d\n", v1, v2); // prints "1 -1"
}
```